# How to convert string to int with different bases?

Tags: c++, hex, base-conversion

I want to convert `string` to `int` but the conversion has to consider the prefixes `0x` or `0` if any and consider the input as `hex` or `oct` respectively. Using `istringstream`, you need to explicitly specify the base. Is there any way than explicitly coding to check for characters `0x`?

*Edit:*
The conversion should implicitly find the base based on the prefix. Just like `int i = 0x123;` does.

Comment: [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) should do that. So should [`stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) family of functions from C++11.

Comment: Yes, it's a nice C++ wrapper for `strtol`.

Comment: @EarlGray: Wrapper? Who said? (+1 BTW)

Comment: @EarlGray, Apart from working when only the first half of the input is valid, it's ok. I don't know if Boost's lexical cast includes these prefixes, but that's a nice option.

Comment: @Nawaz the name suggests some similarity to `strtol/strtoi/strtof`, and the function signature looks like `strtol` with `const char *` replaced by `std::string`

Comment: @EarlGray It *could* use C functions under the hood, but the standard doesn't specify this. I doubt it would be the preferred choice of implementations either.

Comment: @balki I am not sure what supporting base 0 would entail. The implementation I am using seems to try to figure out the base from the input if base 0 is specified.

Comment: @juanchopanza - `stol` etc. were designed to look like `strtol` etc. precisely so they could be implemented by calling the C functions. There's no good reason to rewrite that parsing code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use C function `strtol` : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/
It understands 0x/0 prefices.

Comment: It still needs the third argument to specify the base.

Comment: @balki Just set it to zero, the function will figure out what to use: decimal/octal/hexadecimal numbers.

The third argument is useful for some strange bases or when `0x` prefix is omitted.